# Debug Go tests executed by Makefile

Tags: go, makefile, vscode-debugger

I'm developing in VS Code. We have a makefile that we use to run our end2end tests. It executes a couple docker commands, an export, the go test command (

```
go test -p=1 -count=1 -tags=e2etests ./app_end2end_tests/./...
```

), and cleanup. I tried creating a launch.json and putting the "make e2e" command in a task.json, but the only options for executing the task from launch.json are preLaunchTask and postLaunchTask which don't utilize the debugger. Therefore, I'm wondering how to go about debugging this test suite in its correct environment. Thanks!

Tried: launch.json and task.json. Created a task and set it as preLauchTask in launch.json. The make e2e command was executed but not debugged.

Comment: What's the problem of making vscode directly execute the cited command? The only requirement would be making sure it has the correct current directory when executing (because of `./...`)

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to reliably hook a `make` target to a debugger because in that case the `go test` command will be the 3rd program actually executed: the first is `make`, the second is a shell which executes the target's commands, and the third will be `go test`. I'm not sure there's a reliable way to make the debugger somehow "trap" the execution of a child of a child of a process.